# Php Mysql - Erro na minha função de Error-Logging

Tags: php, mysql

Estou a tentar contruir um sistema de log para erros de php-mysql

Na minha função createtable() eu chamo errorLog() quando preciso de gravar um erro.

```
// Database - CREATE TABLES
    public function createTables($sql) {
        if ($this->connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Tables created successfully<br/>";
        } else {
            $msg = "ERROR - Impossible to create DB";
            $this->errorLog($msg);
        }
    }
    // ****
```

E aqui está a minha função errorLog():

```
// error logging
    public function errorLog($msg) {
        echo $msg."<br/>";
        $user = '';
        $date = date("d/m/Y H:i:s a", time());
        $error = $this->connection->error;
        $state = 1;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `zapp_logs` (`id`, `user`, `date`, `error`, `state`) VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$date', '$error', '$state')";
        if ($this->connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "error logged<br/>";
        } else {
            echo "error not logged: " . $this->connection->error . "<br/>";

        }

    }
```

(Eu sei que o código não está perfeito, ainda estou a tentar melhorar)

Por favor ignorem o facto de existirem variáveis sem valor, ainda estou em fase de desenvolvimento

O meu problema está na funcão errorlog() . 
Dá um erro de sintaxe. Já tentei várias coisas mas não consigo achar o erro.
O código parece executar até $sql

Obrigado pela ajuda e agradeço qualquer melhoria de código que me possam sugerir.

Cumprimentos

Comment: Pode acreditar :) O instalador serve só mesmo para criar a base de dados, e para criar informação de testes , depois a própria pasta do instalador será removida do software final. e as queries dos utilizadores vão passar noutra função.